# Hangouts Chat Bot "The caller does not have permission", PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I created a chat bot using the JAVA Api, based on the sample code from the documentation,
the Bot uses a service account.

The Bot works fine in one Room, but when I try to use it with a new Room I am experiencing an error.

After adding the Bot to the new Room and trying to post a message I receive
{ "code" : 403, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "The caller does not have permission", "reason" : "forbidden" } ], "message" : "The caller does not have permission", "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED" }

Is there any additional step necessary after adding the Bot to a room before posting messages ?

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Code used:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(); 
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory(); 
HangoutsChat.Builder builder = new HangoutsChat.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials); 
builder.setApplicationName(bot); 
HangoutsChat service = builder.build();
```

```
ListSpacesResponse response = service.spaces().list().execute();
// Look for space Space _space = null; 
while (response.getSpaces() != null && _space == null) {    
  for(Space s : response.getSpaces()) {          
    if(s.getDisplayName().equals(space)) {          
      _space = s;       
    }   
  }     
  if (_space == null && response.getNextPageToken() != null && !response.getNextPageToken().isEmpty()) {        
    String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();         
    response = service.spaces().list().setPageToken(pageToken).execute();   
  } else {      
    break;  
  } 
}
```

```
if(_space != null) {    
  Message m = new Message();    
  byte[] data = {0x0A};     
  m.setText(text.replace("\\r", "").replace("\\n", new String(data)));  
  Message r = service.spaces().messages().create(_space.getName(), m).setThreadKey(thread).execute();   
  Element el = new Element("message");  
  el.setAttribute("space", r.getSpace().getDisplayName());  
  el.setAttribute("text", r.getText());     
  el.setAttribute("thread", r.getThread().getName());   
  outNode.addContent(el);  
} else {    
  throw new Exception("SendHangouts failed " + "Space " + space + " not found"); 
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information on the specific steps you're following, including the relevant parts of the code you're using, specially where you are giving the bot access to the room?

Comment: Hi!
I dont have any specific code for adding the Bot to a room.
I just load the service-account credentials, create the HangoutsChat service-object via HangoutsChat.Builder and use it to create messages
service.spaces().messages().create().
I just add the Bot (configured via Developer Console for the Hangouts Chat API)
to a room. (Add People & Bots). This worked so far, but doesnt with new rooms or a room, which name had changed.
Any hints on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!
Regards,
Hans

Comment: Well, could you provide the code you're using for these actions?: `I just load the service-account credentials, create the HangoutsChat service-object via HangoutsChat.Builder and use it to create messages service.spaces().messages().create()`. Also, what do you mean by `new room`? What's the difference between this and and old room, to which the bot can create messages?

Comment: Sorry, my code was too long I had to break it up, is there a better way ?

The exception occurs at the service.spaces().messages().create() call

A new Room is a room where I just added the Bot to.

What kind of difference can Rooms have except a different set of members ?
Are there any more differences which could cause this problem ?

Regards,
Hans

Comment: Can you edit your question with this additional information you provided, so that others can look at it more comfortably?

Comment: I am sorry, it is impossible to edit ma code.

There should be a toolbar, but it is not showing up.

CTRL-K starts actions in the browser ...

How can I edit code properly ?

Regards,
Hans

Comment: `HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HangoutsChat.Builder builder = new HangoutsChat.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials);
builder.setApplicationName(bot);
HangoutsChat service = builder.build();
`

Comment: `ListSpacesResponse response = service.spaces().list().execute();           
// Look for space
Space _space = null;
while (response.getSpaces() != null && _space == null) {
 for(Space s : response.getSpaces()) {
  if(s.getDisplayName().equals(space)) {
   _space = s;
  }
 }
 if (_space == null && response.getNextPageToken() != null && !response.getNextPageToken().isEmpty()) {
  String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
  response = service.spaces().list().setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
 } else {
  break;
 }
}`

Comment: `if(_space != null) {
 Message m = new Message();
 byte[] data = {0x0A};
 m.setText(text.replace("\\r", "").replace("\\n", new String(data)));
 Message r = service.spaces().messages().create(_space.getName(), m).setThreadKey(thread).execute();
 Element el = new Element("message");
 el.setAttribute("space", r.getSpace().getDisplayName());
 el.setAttribute("text", r.getText());
 el.setAttribute("thread", r.getThread().getName());
 outNode.addContent(el);

} else {
 throw new Exception("SendHangouts failed " + "Space " + space + " not found");
}`

Comment: Thats the best I could get.
The error occurs at the service.spaces().messages().create() call.     A new Room is a room where I just added the Bot to. What kind of difference can Rooms have except a different set of members ? Are there any more differences which could cause this problem ? Regards, Hans

Comment: As long as you've added the bot to the room, it should be able to insert messages to the room. The only I can think of is that the service account attached to the bot is not the same one you used to authenticate in your script. Are you sure that's not the case? Also, are you sure the space to which you added the bot is the same one you are trying to send a message to?

Comment: Hi!
I only access the ServiceAccount within my Java code, when I create the Hangouts Service object. I dont access the ServiceAccount anywhere else.
I am sure, that I post to a space where the Bot has eben added, otherwise I wouldn't see the space in the spaces list. And as I said, it works in one particular space.
Thank You for Your ongoing support!
How can I format the code? I wasn't able to accomplish that.
Regards,
Hans.

Comment: You're welcome! This is strange. Can you please check that there is no typo in the space name you provided? (it's case-sensitive). Also, to edit your question, you can click the `edit` option below your question, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Hi!
Because of the fact, that I am iterating over all spaces and compare the DisplayName with the one I want the message to be posted and I am using _space.getName() within the messages().create() call, I dont see any possible problem with the space name. Maybe, somehow, the registration of the Bot doesnt seem to be valid in some spaces, except one. I just added the Bot as a Member to the Rooms. Is there an additional step necessary for Bots ?
Thanx in advance & regards,
Hans

Comment: My question regarding formatting code segments within a post on StackOverflow is still valid, I wasn't able to do that but You were, how can I do that ?
There is also a limit of characters

Comment: You can check how the code is formatted in your question if you click `edit`. You can see that ``` is added before and after each code snippet.

Comment: As long as the bot is a member of the room, there is no additional step necessary for the bot to insert messages there.

Comment: Thanx for Your answer!
Maybe updating the client libraries helps, I will try that.
Regards,
Hans

Comment: ok, I understand that formatting the code is only possible in the question itself, but not in the comments